# Show frontend pages in backend

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, front-end, wrapper

I have a component (in fact it is a ticket system) that only provides ticket editing in the front-end.

However since most of our other important admin functionality is in the backend (administration) I thought maybe just show the particular frontend stuff un an iframe in the backend.

Is there a way/component that does make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as an administrator module:

- Login to the backend
- Go to Extensions - Modules
- Change Site to Administrator
- Create a Custom HTML module and in that module add an iframe code to wrap the ticket page on the frontend.
- Assign that module to the cPanel position (which means that it will show up on the homepage of the backend)

Note that using the above guide may mean that you will need to login twice, once to access the backend, and once to access the frontend ticket system from the backend module.